# Will using export as reult in a large bundle size

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a components library and want to make my imports easier. So I aggregate the components using the following approach.
I use an index.js file in the root of my components folder and using

```
export {default as XComponent} from './x/y/z/XComponent'
export {default as YComponent} from './x/b/c/d/YComponent'
```

So now I can do and not have a large path to write

```
import {X} from '../components
```

Question . Will such an approach result in the situation that when I use the component library in another React app, if import one component, I actually import all of the components ?  So the bundle size is large ?

I thought this wouldn't be the case

Thanks for any comments

Comment: "*I thought this wouldn't be the case*" - but did you experience something else?

Comment: It depends on the bundler you are using. Which you haven't shown, so it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks I would be using webpack , why does it matter ? Any comments are very helpful.